# createElement error in jest test case (Lightning Web Component)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

Error says the component  is not a valid component, or does not extends LightningElement from "lwc". You probably forgot to add the extend clause on the class declaration. Imported LightningElement in js file but still showing error.

```
Signup.js
export default class Signup extends dcBaseMixin(LightningElement)
```

```
SignUp.test.js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from 'vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils';
import { dcBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_cmt/dcBaseMixin';
import Signup from 'c/Signup';

describe('c-signup', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });
    it("should verify the Signup ", () => {    expect(Signup).toBeTruthy();  });
    it('TODO: test case generated by CLI command, please fill in test logic', () => {
        const element =createElement('c-Signup', {
            is: Signup
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        expect(1).toBe(2);
    
    });
});
```

Comment: You have incorrect case "c-Signup" instead of "c-signup".

Comment: even after correction not working, Isuue is probably coming as we are using "export default class Signup extends dcBaseMixin(LightningElement)"

Comment: Did you also correct the case in your import statement?

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: You are probably missing the mock ups for `vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils` & `vlocity_cmt/dcBaseMixin`? or missed declaring them under `moduleNameMapper` in `jest.config.js`? [By default JEST doesn't know about custom namespaces unless you define the mock ups for them]

Comment: I have created those mocks. Actually there is a method inside the dcBaseMixin which may be causing the issue. How do I create a separate mock for a method which is not being identified?